# Fatal error in launcher when trying to do a pip freeze in a venv

Tags: python

Having my virtualenv activated and running:

```
$ pip freeze
```

I get following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process
using ' " "C:\Users\Roy Mertz\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "
"C:\Users\Roy Mertz\Desktop\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" freeze'
```

I get this Fatal error message when I try to do a pip freeze in venv. I am a complete newbie with this stuff, so any answers need to be simplified, please. I have check my pathways, rechecked installs, and don't know how to fix this. I saw the question and answer regarding the fatal error using scripts in virtualenv, but I don't understand the reply. Thank you, in advance, for any help.

Comment: How do you start pip, is it like: `$ pip freeze`? Does `pip` work, if you have venv deactivated? Does the problem happen in other venv or just in this one? What version of `python` do you use? What version of `virtualenv` do you have installed. Do you have multiple Pythons installed? Can you start `$ python`? Can you do `$ python -c "import pip"` and does it crash or it works?

Comment: Whoa! Lots of questions! Lol! ok,...starting pip,..just pip freeze nothing else, no other characters. (I don't know how to highlight in here.) pip works when I'm not in venv. I didn't know there were other venvs. the Python version is 2.7.8. I only have one version installed (I actually uninstalled and reinstalled it, thinking that may fix the problem. It didn't.) Can I start Python in the venv? Yes, just tried it and it works. The last question I don't understand. How would I do that? In the Command Prompt screen, at the end of the command line C:\Users,...etc. type "import pip"?

Comment: Just do it on command line, the `$` is symbol for command line prompt, do not use it, just open a console, activate your virtualenv and type and run `python -c "import pip"`. This shall do nothing, if `pip` can be imported, otherwise it will print some complains.
Regarding "how to write how I call a command on command line" I have edited your question, check how it is written.

Comment: Ok, in venv Python works. I then typed "import pip" (without the quotes) and nothing happened.

Comment: Fine. We can try alternative way of calling `pip`: `$ python -m pip` .. this shall show
help text for command `pip`. Next step is to try `$ python -m pip freeze`.

Comment: Again, that did nothing. $ python -m pip brought up a list of commands and a list of general options. $ python -m pip freeze just brought up the command line.

Comment: I give up. I would repeat this test for virtualenv on path, not containing space. Then the only think I would propose is to completely remove Python, installed `pip`, `virtualenv`, created virtualenvs, check carefully settings of PATH and PYTHONPATH in your system and install every thing again.

Comment: I completely understand about wanting to give! trust me! this is like learning Chinese! I have uninstalled and reinstalled EVERYTHING, python, pip, etc. I checked and rechecked paths and checked the PATH in Environment variables in System settings. It all looks right to me C:Windows\System32;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;